# Mongodb debezium connector populating Rowkey as 0 ( zero ) and Key as 0 zero even though data contain valid values

Tags: json, key, debezium, ksqldb

I have sample Json file that I loaded in mongo db to be sent over to Kafka connect using debezium connector. My question how could RowKey and id key column values converted to 0's ( Zeros ) despite having valid data in raw json input file? Below are the steps followed to produce this error.

Step 1: Create sample json file

```
{"id":1,"first_name":"Devinne","last_name":"Stubbe","email":"dstubbe0@java.com","gender":"Female","club_status":"platinum","comments":"Extended interactive initiative"}
                    {"id":2,"first_name":"Loise","last_name":"Salt","email":"lsalt1@apple.com","gender":"Female","club_status":"silver","comments":"Optimized neutral standardization"}
                    {"id":3,"first_name":"Benjamen","last_name":"Spittle","email":"bspittle2@howstuffworks.com","gender":"Male","club_status":"platinum","comments":"De-engineered systemic customer loyalty"}
                    {"id":4,"first_name":"Helena","last_name":"Pogosian","email":"hpogosian3@pagesperso-orange.fr","gender":"Female","club_status":"gold","comments":"Phased hybrid definition"}
                    {"id":5,"first_name":"Miller","last_name":"Karolewski","email":"mkarolewski4@g.co","gender":"Male","club_status":"platinum","comments":"Monitored systematic software"}
```

Load this data in mongodb in customerprofile collection

```
rs0:PRIMARY> db.collection.find();
        rs0:PRIMARY> db.customerprofile.find();
        { "_id" : ObjectId("5b6213ba78aae5dc09ef8b5b"), "id" : 1, "first_name" : 
        "Devinne", "last_name" : "Stubbe", "email" : "dstubbe0@java.com", "gender" : 
       "Female", "club_st
       atus" : "platinum", "comments" : "Extended interactive initiative" }
       { "_id" : ObjectId("5b6213ba78aae5dc09ef8b5c"), "id" : 2, "first_name" : 
       "Loise", "last_name" : "Salt", "email" : "lsalt1@apple.com", "gender" : 
       "Female", "club_status"
        : "silver", "comments" : "Optimized neutral standardization" }
        { "_id" : ObjectId("5b6213ba78aae5dc09ef8b5d"), "id" : 3, "first_name" : 
        "Benjamen", "last_name" : "Spittle", "email" : "bspittle2@howstuffworks.com", 
        "gender" : "Male"
        , "club_status" : "platinum", "comments" : "De-engineered systemic customer 
        loyalty" }
        { "_id" : ObjectId("5b6213ba78aae5dc09ef8b5e"), "id" : 4, "first_name" : 
        "Helena", "last_name" : "Pogosian", "email" : "hpogosian3@pagesperso- 
       orange.fr", "gender" : "Fe
       male", "club_status" : "gold", "comments" : "Phased hybrid definition" }
       { "_id" : ObjectId("5b6213ba78aae5dc09ef8b5f"), "id" : 5, "first_name" : 
        "Miller", "last_name" : "Karolewski", "email" : "mkarolewski4@g.co", "gender"    
      : "Male", "club_status" : "platinum", "comments" : "Monitored systematic 
       software" }
       { "_id" : ObjectId("5b6213ba78aae5dc09ef8b60"), "id" : 6, "first_name" : 
       "Cammy", "last_name" : "Suche", "email" : "csuche5@cbsnews.com", "gender" : 
       "Male", "club_status" : "gold", "comments" : "Inverse client-server alliance" 
        }
```

Step 2: Create mongodb debezium connector config and activate the connector 
    in kafka connect

```
{
  "name": "mongodb-jsondb-connector",
  "config":{
   "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbConnector",
   "mongodb.hosts": "rs0/169.254.57.118:27017",
   "mongodb.name": "jsondb",
   "mongodb.members.auto.discover": "false",
   "database.whitelist": "jsondb",
    "transforms": "unwrap",
   "transforms.unwrap.type": 
 "io.debezium.connector.mongodb.transforms.UnwrapFromMongoDbEnvelope",
    "database.history.kafka.topic": "schema-changes.jsondb",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
   "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
   "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
   "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false"
 }
}
```

step 3: Check the topic queue

```
  ksql> print 'jsondb.jsondb.customerprofile' from beginning;
   Format:JSON
   {"ROWTIME":1533154567091,"ROWKEY":"
```

As you can see in below output debezium transformed by id column with 
 objectid like

```
 \"id\":\"5b6213ba78aae5dc09ef8b5b\"}","id":"5b6213ba78aae5dc09ef8b5b".
```

****My question how could my id column got updated with serial id key because we used JsonConvetor as key convertor? ****

```
 {\"id\":\"5b6213ba78aae5dc09ef8b5b\"}","id":"5b6213ba78aae5dc09ef8b5b","first_name":"Devinne","last_name":"Stubbe","email":"dstubbe0@java.com","gender":"Female","club_status":"platinum","comments":"Extended interactive initiative"}
    {"ROWTIME":1533154567096,"ROWKEY":" 

  {\"id\":\"5b6213ba78aae5dc09ef8b5c\"}","id":"5b6213ba78aae5dc09ef8b5c","first_name":"Loise","last_name":"Salt","email":"lsalt1@apple.com","gender":"Female","club_status":"silver","comments":"Optimized neutral standardization"}
    {"ROWTIME":1533154567096,"ROWKEY":" 

 {\"id\":\"5b6213ba78aae5dc09ef8b5d\"}","id":"5b6213ba78aae5dc09ef8b5d","first_name":"Benjamen","last_name":"Spittle","email":"bspittle2@howstuffworks.com","gender":"Male","club_status":"platinum","comments":"De-engineered systemic customer loyalty"}
{"ROWTIME":1533154567097,"ROWKEY":"{\"id\":\"5b6213ba78aae5dc09ef8b5e\"}","id":"5b6213ba78aae5dc09ef8b5e","first_name":"Helena","last_name":"Pogosian","email":"hpogosian3@pagesperso-orange.fr","gender":"Female","club_status":"gold","comments":"Phased hybrid definition"}
{"ROWTIME":1533154567097,"ROWKEY":"{\"id\":\"5b6213ba78aae5dc09ef8b5f\"}","id":"5b6213ba78aae5dc09ef8b5f","first_name":"Miller","last_name":"Karolewski","email":"mkarolewski4@g.co","gender":"Male","club_status":"platinum","comments":"Monitored systematic software"}
{"ROWTIME":1533154567099,"ROWKEY":"{\"id\":\"5b6213ba78aae5dc09ef8b60\"}","id":"5b6213ba78aae5dc09ef8b60","first_name":"Cammy","last_name":"Suche","email":"csuche5@cbsnews.com","gender":"Male","club_status":"gold","comments":"Inverse client-server alliance"}
```

Step 4: Create a stream from the topic queue

```
   CREATE STREAM customers_profile \
    (id integer, first_name string, last_name string, \
     email string, gender string, club_status string, \
    comments string) WITH \ 
    (KAFKA_TOPIC='jsondb.jsondb.customerprofile',VALUE_FORMAT='json');
```

Step 5:  This is where stream is receiving zero's (0's) from CUSTOMER_REPART

```
ksql> CREATE STREAM customers_stream WITH 
 (KAFKA_TOPIC='CUSTOMERS_REPART',VALUE_FORMAT='json',PARTITIONS=1) as SELECT * 
 FROM customers_profile PARTITION BY id;
```

Step 6: Please check the output from this print command where it shows Zero's 
       in ROWKEY and id key column values. Where did they came from? What I need 
    to do to make sure the ROWKEY and id key column shows correct values from raw 
     json file values that were originally loaded in mongodb?

```
ksql> SET 'auto.offset.reset' = 'earliest';
        Successfully changed local property 'auto.offset.reset' from 'null' to 
        'earliest'
        ksql> print 'CUSTOMERS_REPART' from beginning;
        Format:JSON
```

{"ROWTIME":1533154567091,"ROWKEY":"0","CLUB_STATUS":"platinum","GENDER":"Female","COMMENTS":"Extended interactive initiative","ID":0,"LAST_NAME":"Stubbe","EMAIL":"dstubbe0@
    {"ROWTIME":1533154567096,"ROWKEY":"0","CLUB_STATUS":"silver","GENDER":"Female","COMMENTS":"Optimized neutral standardization","ID":0,"LAST_NAME":"Salt","EMAIL":"lsalt1@appl
    {"ROWTIME":1533154567096,"ROWKEY":"0","CLUB_STATUS":"platinum","GENDER":"Male","COMMENTS":"De-engineered systemic customer loyalty","ID":0,"LAST_NAME":"Spittle","EMAIL":"bs":"Benjamen"}
    {"ROWTIME":1533154567097,"ROWKEY":"0","CLUB_STATUS":"gold","GENDER":"Female","COMMENTS":"Phased hybrid definition","ID":0,"LAST_NAME":"Pogosian","EMAIL":"hpogosian3@pagespe
    {"ROWTIME":1533154567097,"ROWKEY":"0","CLUB_STATUS":"platinum","GENDER":"Male","COMMENTS":"Monitored systematic software","ID":0,"LAST_NAME":"Karolewski","EMAIL":"mkarolews
    {"ROWTIME":1533154567099,"ROWKEY":"0","CLUB_STATUS":"gold","GENDER":"Male","COMMENTS":"Inverse client-server alliance","ID":0,"LAST_NAME":"Suche","EMAIL":"csuche5@cbsnews.c
    {"ROWTIME":1533154567104,"ROWKEY":"0","CLUB_STATUS":"platinum","GENDER":"Male","COMMENTS":"Phased uniform software","ID":0,"LAST_NAME":"Suttling","EMAIL":"msuttling7@baidu.
    {"ROWTIME":1533154567104,"ROWKEY":"0","CLUB_STATUS":"gold","GENDER":"Female","COMMENTS":"Quality-focused global software","ID":0,"LAST_NAME":"Stepney","EMAIL":"estepney8@we

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your first question, I think you are seeing an effect of https://github.com/debezium/debezium/blob/master/debezium-connector-mongodb/src/main/java/io/debezium/connector/mongodb/transforms/UnwrapFromMongoDbEnvelope.java#L163

Regarding your second question, I think the problem is `id integer` as the ids now contains strings.